# Pinging a list of network printers

Tags: powershell

Have a list of printers from a print server, trying to ping them, but getting an error.

```
$printers = import-csv C:\users\me\Desktop\print2.csv
foreach ($printer in $printers) {test-connection $printer -count 1}
```

test-connection : Testing connection to computer '@{printers =pr1466}' failed: A non-recoverable error occurred during a 
database lookup

I know this printer is active and pings back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call Import-Csv, it uses the first row as a header row, which are used as property names on the imported objects. In your case, it looks like the name of the single header column is "Printers", so you'd do this:

```
foreach ($printer in $printers) {test-connection $printer.printers -count 1};
```

You could change the header row to something more appropriate, such as "Name" and then you'd use the following code, which reads a bit more nicely:

```
foreach ($printer in $printers) {test-connection $printer.Name -count 1};
```

Comment: thank you, that worked.  Feel like Ill never get the hang of the syntax!

Comment: You'll get it mate. Use Get-Member to help you discover properties on objects.